# XSLT for-each with and condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml with multiple nodes and I am trying to fetch nodes based on an 'and' condition using xpath 1.0. I tried using contains in the for-each clause, when I use just one [contains(DateType, 'CAOSL')] it returns the result but when I add the 'and' clause the result is not returned even though there are 2 node that match the condition. 
  I would appreciate if someone can point out what's wrong or point me to the correct way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried the for-each as below in the xslt file. The first one returns the node with matching CAOSL but the and condition fails.

XML:

```
<Products>
<Product>
    <ProductSupply>
        <SupplyDetail>
            <Supplier>
                <SupplierRole>01</SupplierRole>
                <SuppierName>Test</SuppierName>
            </Supplier>
            <ProductAvailability>21</ProductAvailability>
            <SupplyDate>
                <SupplyDateRole>00</SupplyDateRole>
                <Date>1464739200</Date>
                <DateCountry>NZ</DateCountry>
                <DateType>NZPUB</DateType>
            </SupplyDate>
            <SupplyDate>
                <SupplyDateRole>00</SupplyDateRole>
                <Date>1464739200</Date>
                <DateCountry>AU</DateCountry>
                <DateType>AUPUB</DateType>
            </SupplyDate>
            <SupplyDate>
                <SupplyDateRole>00</SupplyDateRole>
                <Date>1496102400</Date>
                <DateCountry>CA</DateCountry>
                <DateType>CAOSL</DateType>
            </SupplyDate>
            <SupplyDate>
                <SupplyDateRole>00</SupplyDateRole>
                <Date>1480550400</Date>
                <DateCountry>UK</DateCountry>
                <DateType>UKOSL</DateType>
            </SupplyDate>
            <SupplyDate>
                <SupplyDateRole>00</SupplyDateRole>
                <Date>1464739200</Date>
                <DateCountry>NZ</DateCountry>
                <DateType>NZSHD</DateType>
            </SupplyDate>
            <SupplyDate>
                <SupplyDateRole>02</SupplyDateRole>
                <Date>1463961600</Date>
                <DateCountry>AU</DateCountry>
                <DateType>AUOSL</DateType>
            </SupplyDate>
            <SupplyDate>
                <SupplyDateRole>00</SupplyDateRole>
                <Date>1464566400</Date>
                <DateCountry>NZ</DateCountry>
                <DateType>NZOSL</DateType>
            </SupplyDate>
            <SupplyDate>
                <SupplyDateRole>08</SupplyDateRole>
                <Date>1464739200</Date>
                <DateCountry>AU</DateCountry>
                <DateType>AUSHD</DateType>
            </SupplyDate>
            <SupplyDate>
                <SupplyDateRole>00</SupplyDateRole>
                <Date>1496102400</Date>
                <DateCountry>US</DateCountry>
                <DateType>USOSL</DateType>
            </SupplyDate>
        </SupplyDetail>
    </ProductSupply>
</Product>
```

XSLT:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="Products">
    <Products>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Product" />
    </Products>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Product">
    <product>
      <productsupply>
        <supplydetail>
          <xsl:for-each select="ProductSupply/SupplyDetail/SupplyDate[contains(DateType, 'CAOSL') and contains(DateType, 'USOSL')]">
            <supplydate>
              <DateType>
                <xsl:value-of select="DateType" />
              </DateType>
              <DateCountry>
                <xsl:value-of select="DateCountry" />
              </DateCountry>
            </supplydate>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </supplydetail>
      </productsupply>
    </product>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<result>
<SupplyDate>
    <SupplyDateRole>00</SupplyDateRole>
    <Date>1496102400</Date>
    <DateCountry>CA</DateCountry>
    <DateType>CAOSL</DateType>
</SupplyDate>
<SupplyDate>
    <SupplyDateRole>00</SupplyDateRole>
    <Date>1496102400</Date>
    <DateCountry>US</DateCountry>
    <DateType>USOSL</DateType>
</SupplyDate>
```

Comment: I think you want to use OR instead of AND?

Comment: Also, you likely do not need `xsl:for-each` but can use templates.

Answer (score 1):

Your data does not include a SupplyDate that has both a DateType containing CAOSL and a DateType containing USOSL.

So your logic is incorrect, but I can't work out from your question what your actual requirement is.

Incidentally, I think you have misunderstood what `contains()` does, though that's not your main bug. Given an element ABCXYZ, `contains(a, "ABC")` returns true. I think you want `a = "ABC"` which returns true only if ABC is the entire string value of the node.